# Return Result<Cow<[u8]>> instead of Result<Vec<u8>>

Tags: rust, file-io

I would like to change this function to return a `Result<Cow<[u8]>>` instead to avoid copying the whole file to memory unnecessarily.

```
pub(crate) fn get_reader_bytes<R: Read + MmapBytesReader>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    // we have a file so we can mmap
    if let Some(file) = reader.to_file() {
        let mmap = unsafe { memmap::Mmap::map(file)? };
        Ok(mmap[..].to_vec())
    } else {
        // we can get the bytes for free
        if let Some(bytes) = reader.to_bytes() {
            Ok(bytes.to_vec())
        } else {
            // we have to read to an owned buffer to get the bytes.
            let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(1024 * 128);
            reader.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
            if !bytes.is_empty()
                && (bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\n' || bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\r')
            {
                bytes.push(b'\n')
            }
            Ok(bytes)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the code below but got `error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data *mmap` which makes sense.

```
pub(crate) fn get_reader_bytes<R: Read + MmapBytesReader>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<Cow<[u8]>>     {
      // we have a file so we can mmap
      if let Some(file) = reader.to_file() {
          let mmap = unsafe { memmap::Mmap::map(file)? };
          Ok(Cow::Borrowed(&mmap[..]))
      } else {
          // we can get the bytes for free
          if let Some(bytes) = (*reader).to_bytes() {
              Ok(Cow::Borrowed(bytes))
          } else {
              // we have to read to an owned buffer to get the bytes.
              let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(1024 * 128);
              reader.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
              if !bytes.is_empty()
                  && (bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\n' || bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\r')
              {
                  bytes.push(b'\n')
              }
              Ok(Cow::Owned(bytes))
          }
      }
  }
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, do I need to create mmap before the function is called and pass it as a mutable reference? Or an Option of a mutable reference? Or a mutable reference of an Option?

Comment: What is `MmapBytesReader`? It is not part of the standard library, nor was I able to find anything on crates.io with a trait of that name.

Comment: Sorry, its here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/polars/polars-io/src/mmap.rs

Comment: Here's a playground https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e72944c1396a59227993eb43541630fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
      if let Some(file) = reader.to_file() {
          let mmap = unsafe { memmap::Mmap::map(file)? };
          Ok(Cow::Borrowed(&mmap[..]))
```

The problem starts here: you're creating a new `Mmap`, **which is responsible for the existence of the memory mapping,** as a local variable. So, the `Mmap` is dropped at the end of the function, and the reference is invalid since the memory mapping no longer exists.

The closest thing to this that you *can* do is to return the `Mmap` itself — or rather, in this case, return an enum of your own design, not `Cow`, which can then provide the logic to borrow any of its variants (just as `Cow` does):

```rust
enum MyBytes<'a> {
    Borrowed(&'a [u8]),
    Owned(Vec<u8>),
    Mapped(memmap::Mmap),
}

impl std::ops::Deref for MyBytes<'_> {
    type Target = [u8];
    fn deref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        match self {
            Self::Borrowed(ref_bytes) => ref_bytes,
            Self::Owned(vec) => &vec,
            Self::Mapped(mmap) => &mmap,
        }
    }
}
```

Then use that enum inside `get_reader_bytes`:

```rust
pub(crate) fn get_reader_bytes<R: Read + MmapBytesReader>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<MyBytes<'_>, std::io::Error>     {
      // we have a file so we can mmap
      if let Some(file) = reader.to_file() {
          let mmap = unsafe { memmap::Mmap::map(file)? };
          Ok(MyBytes::Mapped(mmap))
      } else {
          // we can get the bytes for free
          if reader.to_bytes().is_some() {
              Ok(MyBytes::Borrowed(reader.to_bytes().unwrap()))
          } else {
              // we have to read to an owned buffer to get the bytes.
              let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(1024 * 128);
              reader.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
              if !bytes.is_empty()
                  && (bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\n' || bytes[bytes.len() - 1] != b'\r')
              {
                  bytes.push(b'\n')
              }
              Ok(MyBytes::Owned(bytes))
          }
      }
}
```

Notice awkwardness in the Borrowed case: I had to call `to_bytes()` twice. This is because the borrow checker does not currently support the pattern where you do something with a *mutable* reference, then either return a borrow that depends on it or drop that borrow and do something else — it assumes the borrow unconditionally extends to the end of the function, preventing you from doing anything else with the mutable reference. So, in this situation, we *must* separate the check that a byte slice is available from the action of returning such a slice.

A better solution to this would be to put the reading logic *inside the MmapBytesReader trait implementations* (possibly in the form of separate functions that the impls call, so multiple impls can share the code), so that there's no `if` branching at all to confuse the borrow checker.